# WebGL - culling mesh and hide the border

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have the following problem in WebGL.
I 'm drawing a a simple mesh with a border in the 3D space with the culling activated.

```
gl.frontFace(gl.CCW);
gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT)
```

If the camera is set in front of the mesh, it is correcly visualized with the border
[FrontView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjbPF.png)

But if the camere is set back the mesh the border does not disappear
[BackView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvoCd.png)

The internal part of the mesh is draw as triangles

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexBuffer.numberOfItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

while the border as LINE_STRIP

```
gl.drawElements(gl.LINE_STRIP, borderIndex.numberOfItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Is there any option for lines to have the same behavior of the mesh without using normals in the shader?

Answer (score 0):

While triangles have an inherent front and back face based on their winding order lines don't have that so they're not affected by hardware culling.